# I have created custom button in admin site and click on it goes to views get_changeform_initial_data() function and put some static value in form

Tags: django, django-views, django-admin

<--(same here in example tickets_open and tickets_closed getting some static value but the problem is these values are not showing in admin forms)-->

```
from hellogymapp.admin import BillingAdmin, TechAdmin
def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
    return {
        'tickets_open': 145,
        'tickets_closed' :123
    }
```

Comment: but Django admin showing error ( Billing with ID "add/action" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted? )

Comment: Can you edit the question? What are you asking about is not clear from the question and it will be downvoted if you won't make it clear.

Comment: the question is still not specifi enough. Can you write in the question body (it's better than putting it in the topic), what is the HTML of the button you are using. Where you want it to direct and from what view you want it to be used? Right now there is not enough context for anyone to answer your question.